# Camera and library actions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm pretty much new in Swift coding and I have a problem with camera and library usage. I have this part of the code:

```
    @IBAction func camera(_ sender: Any) {

    if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        return
    }

    let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraPicker.delegate = self
    cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera
    cameraPicker.allowsEditing = false

    present(cameraPicker, animated: true)
}

@IBAction func openLibrary(_ sender: Any) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true)
}
```

}

and in cameraPicker.delegate = self and picker.delegate = self throws an error like this one:

> Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type '(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?'

I really have no idea how to fix this. I would be thankful if anyone could help me with this one, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to add the delegate like

```
class ViewConroller: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
   ...
}
```